# Естественная сортировка (natural order) и ActiveRecord в Yii2

Tags: php, сортировка, yii2

Использую [Active Record в Yii2](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html), и получаю список в такой последовательности (*сортировка по ASCII, ASCIIbetical order*):

- Pacific 12°-28° 1200w 80v
- Pacific 14°-35° 1200w 80v
- Pacific 23°-50° 1200w 80v
- **Pacific 5.5°-13° 1200w 80v**

Однако [нормальный пользователь (не программист!) ожидает, что](http://blog.codinghorror.com/sorting-for-humans-natural-sort-order/) последний из элементов будет в начале. **Естественная сортировка** (*natural order, сортировка по алфавиту*):

- **Pacific 5.5°-13° 1200w 80v**
- Pacific 12°-28° 1200w 80v
- Pacific 14°-35° 1200w 80v
- Pacific 23°-50° 1200w 80v

В PHP возможность использовать естественную сортировку есть по умолчанию (что, кстати, [преимущество языка по сравнению с другими](http://www.davekoelle.com/alphanum.html)):

- функция [natsort()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.natsort.php)
- функция [sort() с флагом SORT_NATURAL](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.sort.php)
- функция [strnatcmp()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.strnatcmp.php)

Но вот использование фреймворка Yii2, похоже, сводит это преимущество на нет. Я получаю тот самый "*ASCIIbetical order*", который нужно как-то пересортировывать. Дополнительная засада зарыта в [виджете GridView](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-grid-gridview.html), который если и получит отсортированный список, то при сортировке по клику на ярлык колонки перестроит список опять же как в первом примере.

Есть ли возможность "минимальной кровью" подружить Yii2 и естественную сортировку?

P.S. В [указанной выше статье](http://blog.codinghorror.com/sorting-for-humans-natural-sort-order/) есть чудный фрагмент:

> Я не могу понять одну тупую вещь. Боже мой, люди. Вы программисты.
>   Почти у всех высшее образование, но никто из вас не знает, что черт
>   подери значит *"по алфавиту"*. Вам должно быть стыдно. Если вы
>   используете для сортировки по алфавиту дефолтный алгоритм языка 
>   программирования — 
>   *скорее всего, это сортировка по ASCII (по хорошей причине)*, —
>   то идите к ближайшему зеркалу и дайте себе
>   несколько пощечин, а потом вернитесь на рабочие места и исправьте
>   юнит-тесты, которые не ловят эту проблему.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Неделю я воевал с PHP и MySQL, выясняя нюансы работы с сортировкой. Грабли лежат на каждом шагу. Например, 
[natcasesort()](http://php.net/natcasesort) - учитывает регистр, но спотыкается о цифры:

- Рабочая станция визуализации/файл-сервер системы
- рабочая станция художника по свету
- Тубус Pacific 12°-28°
- Тубус Pacific 14°-35°
- Тубус Pacific 23°-50°
- **Тубус Pacific 5.5°-13°** *(элемент списка не на месте)*

[sort($lines, SORT_NATURAL | SORT_FLAG_CASE)](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.sort.php) - упорядочивает смесь цифр и букв, но спотыкается о регистр, если есть кириллица:

- Рабочая станция визуализации/файл-сервер системы
- Тубус Pacific 5.5°-13°
- Тубус Pacific 12°-28°
- Тубус Pacific 14°-35°
- Тубус Pacific 23°-50°
- **рабочая станция художника по свету** *(элемент не на месте)*

Важный теоретический момент: **MySQL не умеет делать естественную сортировку, а Yii2 получает данные в том порядке, в каком из отдает база данных.** Поэтому вместо сортировки по буквенно-цифровому полю стоит использовать сортировку по полю вспомогательному. О реализации этой идеи - ниже. Не буду рассказывать о всех деталях, расскажу о ключевых.

Создаем вспомогательное поле (ниже - *sequence*). В нем будем хранить целые числа (*int*). Элементы списка пронумерованы сотнями начиная со ста. Это позволит нам добавлять новые элементы не пересчитывая всю последовательность. Со ста начинаем, чтобы можно было добавлять элементы в начало списка и не заморачиваться с отрицательными числами. Аналогичный рецепт есть у [Александра Макарова в блоге](http://rmcreative.ru/blog/post/kak-khranit-uporjadochennyy-spisok-v-baze-dannykh), только он предлагает хранить последовательность в виде *decimal*. Этот момент совершенно непринципиален, выбирайте то, что больше нравится.

Теперь нам нужно просчитать последовательность для имеющегося списка. Я создал класс *CyrrilicHandler*, в котором есть несколько методов, связанных с этой задачей:

```
    public function upperletters()
    {
        return [
            'А','Б','В','Г','Д','Е','Ё','Ж','З','И','Й','К','Л','М','Н','О','П',
            'Р','С','Т','У','Ф','Х','Ц','Ч','Ш','Щ','Ъ','Ы','Ь','Э','Ю','Я',
        ];
    }

    public function lowerletters()
    {
        return [
            'а','б','в','г','д','е','ё','ж','з','и','й','к','л','м','н','о','п',
            'р','с','т','у','ф','х','ц','ч','ш','щ','ъ','ы','ь','э','ю','я',
        ];
    }

    // Приводим строку к нижнему регистру
    public function strtolower($string)
    {
        return str_replace(self::upperletters(), self::lowerletters(), $string);    
    }

    // Приводим строку к верхнему регистру
    public function strtoupper($string)
    {
        return str_replace(self::lowerletters(), self::upperletters(), $string);    
    }

    // Естественная регистронезависимая сортировка (базовая латиница + кириллица)
    public function sort($array = [])
    {
        $complexArray = [];

        foreach ($array as $value) {
            $complexArray[] = [
                'value'     => $value,
                'lowercase' => self::strtolower($value),
            ];
        }

        ArrayHelper::multisort($complexArray, ['lowercase'], [SORT_ASC], SORT_NATURAL | SORT_FLAG_CASE);
        return ArrayHelper::getColumn($complexArray, 'value');
    }

    // Естественная регистронезависимая сортировка с возможностью задать первый
    // ключ возвращаемого массива и интервал между элементами
    // Первый элемент - 100, далее - с интервалом 100
    public function sortAndSetInitialAndInterval($array = [])
    {
        $raw = self::sort($array);
        $res = [];

        $key = 100; // начинаем последовательность со ста

        foreach ($raw as $value) {
            $res[$key] = $value;
            $key += 100; // интервал - 100
        }

        return $res;
    }
```

Обновляем имеющиеся данные:

```
$lines = Line::find()
    ->select('line')
    ->orderBy('line')
    ->column();

// Естественная регистронезависимая сортировка
$lines = CyrrilicHandler::sortAndSetInitialAndInterval($lines);

$table = Line::tableName();

foreach ($lines as $sequence => $line):

    $query = "UPDATE {$table} 
                 SET sequence = :sequence
               WHERE line = :line";

    Yii::$app->db->createCommand($query)
        ->bindValue(':sequence', $sequence)
        ->bindValue(':line', $line)
        ->execute();

endforeach; // $lines as $sequence => $line
```

Проделывать такую операцию каждый раз не хочется, поэтому я создал метод newPosition(), который возвращает номер в существующей последовательности для заданной строки. Вот этот метод и методы, связанные с ним (*CyrrilicHandler*):

```
    // Поиск позиции нового элемента в последовательности (чтобы не обновлять все записи 
    // последовательности)
    public function newPosition($string)
    {
        // В зависимости от первого символа строки (цифра или нет) получаем разные блоки данных
        $block = self::isInitialSymbolNumber($string) ? self::findEntriesStartedWithNumber() :
                                                            self::findEntriesStartedWithSameSymbol($string);

        if (sizeof($block)) {

            // Если переданная строка уже есть в БД, возвращаем ее позицию
            if (array_search($string, $block) !== false)
                return array_search($string, $block);

            list($before, $after) = self::analyseBlockWithString($block, $string);
        } else {
            list($before, $after) = self::analyseBordersWithString($string);
        }

        return $before + floor(($after - $before)/2);
    }

    // Проверяем первый символ (цифра или нет)
    private function isInitialSymbolNumber($string) {
        return is_numeric(mb_substr($string, 0, 1, 'UTF-8'));
    }

    private function findEntriesStartedWithNumber()
    {
        return Line::find()
            ->select('line')
            ->where("line REGEXP '^[0-9]'")
            ->orderBy('sequence')
            ->indexBy('sequence')
            ->column();
    }

    private function findEntriesStartedWithSameSymbol($string)
    {
        return Line::find()
            ->select('line')
            ->where(['like', 'line', mb_substr($string, 0, 1, 'UTF-8') . '%', false])
            ->orderBy('sequence')
            ->indexBy('sequence')
            ->column();
    }

    private function analyseBlockWithString($block, $string)
    {
        // Добавляем в блок строку и сортируем, исходный блок остается неизменным
        $sorted = self::sort(array_merge($block, ['x' => $string]));

        // Находим номер нового элемента в отсортированной последовательности
        $eid = array_search($string, $sorted);

        $before = isset($sorted[$eid-1]) ? array_search($sorted[$eid-1], $block) : false;
        $after  = isset($sorted[$eid+1]) ? array_search($sorted[$eid+1], $block) : false;        

        if ($before && $after)
            return [$before, $after];

        // Если строка на границе - нужны доп. данные из БД 
        if (!$before)
            $before = self::findBeforeByAfter($after) ?: 0;

        if (!$after)
            $after = self::findAfterByBefore($before) ?: array_pop(array_keys($block)) + 100;

        return [$before, $after];
    }

    private function analyseBordersWithString($string)
    {
        $before = self::findPreviousEntryNumber($string) ?: 0;
        $after  = self::findAfterByBefore($before) ?: false;

        // Если не нашлось ничего ни до ни после (первая запись в БД)
        if ($before === 0 && !$after)
            $after = 200;

        if ($before !== 0 && $after)
            return [$before, $after];

        // Добавляемая строка попадает в конец списка, т.к. интервал 100, то суммируем двойной интервал
        // (позже разделится на 2)
        return [$before, $before + 200];
    }

    private function findPreviousEntryNumber($string)
    {
        return self::isInitialSymbolNumber($string) ? self::findPreviousStartedWithNumber() :
                                                        self::findPreviousStartedWithNotNumber($string);
    }

    private function findPreviousStartedWithNumber()
    {
        return Line::find()
            ->select('sequence')
            ->where(['<', 'line', 0])
            ->orderBy('sequence DESC')
            ->limit(1)
            ->scalar();
    }

    private function findPreviousStartedWithNotNumber($string)
    {
        return Line::find()
            ->select('sequence')
            ->where(['<', 'line', $string])
            ->orderBy('sequence DESC')
            ->limit(1)
            ->scalar();
    }

    // Находим следующий номер за указанным
    private function findAfterByBefore($number)
    {
        return Line::find()
            ->select('sequence')
            ->where(['>', 'sequence', $number])
            ->orderBy('sequence ASC')
            ->limit(1)
            ->scalar();
    }

    // Находим номер, предыдущий указанному
    private function findBeforeByAfter($number)
    {
        return Line::find()
            ->select('sequence')
            ->where(['<', 'sequence', $number])
            ->orderBy('sequence DESC')
            ->limit(1)
            ->scalar();
    }
```

Чтобы результат стал виден пользователям, указываем поле, по которому будем сортировать данные в параметрах сортировки провайдера данных:

```
[
    'defaultOrder' => [
        'sequence' => SORT_ASC,
    ],
    'attributes' => [
        'line' => [
            'asc' => ['sequence' => SORT_ASC],
            'desc' => ['sequence' => SORT_DESC],
        ],
    ],
];
```

Буду рад замечаниям и уточнениям.

Comment: Полезная информация. Спасибо.